# Adding the custom policy to the Role (taskRole)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I am trying to add policystatement to task.

What I made now is like this below.

```
const myBucketPolicy = new iam.PolicyStatement({
  effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
  actions: [
    "s3:PutObject*"
  ],
  resources: [
    up_bk.bucketArn,
    up_bk.bucketArn + "/*"
  ],
});
```

try to add this to the fargate taskrole.

```
props!.taskDefinitionAdmin.taskRole.addToResourcePolicy(myBucketPolicy);
```

However, this error comes.

```
Property 'addToResourcePolicy' does not exist on type 'IRole'.
```

So basically, my idea is wrong.

How can I add the custom policy to the role?

---

Solution using attachInlinePolicy

```
const pushacl = new iam.PolicyStatement({
  effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
  actions: [
    "s3:PutObject*"
  ],
  resources: [
    "*"
  ],
});

const pushaclpolicy = new iam.Policy(this, 'pushs3acl-policy', {
  statements: [pushacl]
});

taskDefinitionAdmin.taskRole.attachInlinePolicy(pushaclpolicy);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be using [attachInlinePolicy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_iam.Role.html#attachwbrinlinewbrpolicypolicy), instead of `addToResourcePolicy`.